# Simple mocha testing setup

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am using Mocha for testing a Node.js command line app:

```
 describe('#call', function () {
        var nconf = require('nconf'); //is this the best place for this?
        before(function () {
            //var nconf = require('nconf'); i'd rather define it here
            nconf.use('memory');
            nconf.set('fp','data_for_testing/csvfile.csv');
            nconf.set('mptp','map_ivr_itg');  
            nconf.set('NODE_ENV','dev_local');
        });
        it('should run without throwing an error or timing out', function (done) {
            var start = require('../lib/setup');
            start.forTesting(done);
            start.run(nconf); //need nconf to be defined here
        });
    });
```

I want to use the Mocha framework right, but the only way I can get the `nconf` var defined in the `it()` function is to define it outside the `before()` function. Is the best way to do it?

Comment: `var nconf = null; 
        before(function () {
            nconf = require('nconf'); 
            nconf.use('memory');
        });`

Comment: ^^would look more readable as a code formatted answer :)

Comment: You say you want it defined inside the `before` call but you do not specify any reason why. If there is no compelling reason for you to call `require` inside the `before` then it is wholly a matter of *opinion* where the call should go. I organize my Mocha files so that they test one library per file. With this organization, there is no discernible benefit to have the `require` call anywhere else than at the top, with all the other calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Yury Tarabanko posted in the comments, the best way to do it is to create the nconf variable outside of the before() and reassign it, on each before run.

```
describe('#call', function () {
    var nconf = null; // scope of variable is the whole #call tests

    before(function () {
        nconf = require('nconf'); // will reassign before each test
        nconf.use('memory');
        nconf.set('fp','data_for_testing/csvfile.csv');
        nconf.set('mptp','map_ivr_itg');  
        nconf.set('NODE_ENV','dev_local');
    });

    it('should run without throwing an error or timing out', function (done) {
        var start = require('../lib/setup');
        start.forTesting(done);
        start.run(nconf); // nconf is in scope
    });
});
```